# synchronous exception on branch and link

Tags: c, arm64

Hello I am writing a small program to run on ARMv8 processor. All worked well until I added more functions. Now when calling a new function, the processor enters into a synchronous exception, but I cannot tell why and what went wrong. `ESR_EL3` is as follow: `EC=0, IL=1, ISS=0`. `ELR_EL3` points to the function on which the processor generates the exception. Where should I look to find what went wrong? The program is writen in C. Best regards

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x80800
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          24536 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         4
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         8
  Section header string table index: 7

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000080120  00000120
       000000000000398c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1024
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000084000  00004000
       0000000000000753  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000085000  00005000
       0000000000000001  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000086000  00006000
       0000000000000040  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 5] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00005008
       0000000000000ac8  0000000000000018           6    48     8
  [ 6] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00005ad0
       00000000000004ce  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00005f9e
       0000000000000034  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000080000 0x0000000000080000
                 0x0000000000003aac 0x0000000000003aac  R E    0x10000
  LOAD           0x0000000000004000 0x0000000000084000 0x0000000000084000
                 0x0000000000000753 0x0000000000000753  R      0x10000
  LOAD           0x0000000000005000 0x0000000000085000 0x0000000000085000
                 0x0000000000000001 0x0000000000000001  RW     0x10000
  LOAD           0x0000000000006000 0x0000000000086000 0x0000000000086000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000040  RW     0x10000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .rodata 
   02     .data 
   03     .bss 

There is no dynamic section in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type AArch64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 115 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000080120     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000084000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000085000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000086000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bcm2835.c
     6: 0000000000080120     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS dtb.c
     8: 0000000000080128     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
     9: 0000000000080128    68 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 endian_conv_u32
    10: 0000000000084000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
    11: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS elf.c
    12: 00000000000841c8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
    13: 0000000000080500     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    14: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS entry.s
    15: 0000000000080800     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    16: 0000000000081388     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $d
    17: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS heap.c
    18: 0000000000086000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 $d
    19: 00000000000813a0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    20: 00000000000841e8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
    21: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS log.c
    22: 0000000000086010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 $d
    23: 0000000000081818     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    24: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.c
    25: 0000000000084210     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
    26: 0000000000081934     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    27: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS pmm.c
    28: 0000000000081b98     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    29: 0000000000081c48    88 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 pmm_check
    30: 0000000000081ca0   500 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 pmm_merge
    31: 0000000000081e94   512 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 pmm_split_by_addr
    32: 0000000000082094   436 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 pmm_split_by_size
    33: 0000000000084450     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $d
    34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS spinlock.s
    35: 00000000000829bc     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    36: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS stack.c
    37: 0000000000086018     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 $d
    38: 00000000000829e0     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    39: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS string.c
    40: 0000000000082a40     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    41: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS tree.c
    42: 00000000000832a8     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $x
    43: 00000000000832a8    40 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 tree_height_max
    44: 00000000000832d0    44 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 tree_height
    45: 00000000000832fc    84 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 tree_rotate_left
    46: 0000000000083350    84 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 tree_rotate_right
    47: 0000000000083550   116 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 tree_remove_left
    48: 0000000000080800     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 entry
    49: 0000000000081818   284 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 log
    50: 000000000008298c    48 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_debug
    51: 0000000000082b84   296 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_format2x
    52: 0000000000081ac0    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_spx_serror
    53: 0000000000080120     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 bcm2835_init
    54: 0000000000086010     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 log_spinlock
    55: 000000000008038c   372 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 dtb_parse
    56: 00000000000827c0    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_del
    57: 00000000000833a4   428 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_insert
    58: 0000000000081b50    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch32_irq
    59: 0000000000081a00    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_sp0_serror
    60: 0000000000081ad8    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch64_syn
    61: 00000000000801dc   432 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 dtb_struct
    62: 0000000000082248   664 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_alloc
    63: 0000000000086028     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 main_ok
    64: 0000000000086008     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 heap_head
    65: 00000000000813b4    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 heap_extend
    66: 0000000000082ad4    64 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_length
    67: 0000000000086030     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 pmm_spinlock
    68: 0000000000082cac   388 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_format2d
    69: 00000000000829bc     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 spinlock_acquire
    70: 0000000000081790   136 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 heap_debug
    71: 00000000000813cc   688 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 heap_alloc
    72: 0000000000085000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 entry_data
    73: 00000000000837d4    88 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_max
    74: 0000000000082e30   968 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_format2
    75: 00000000000831f8   176 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_format
    76: 00000000000824e0   336 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_free
    77: 00000000000819e8    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_sp0_fiq
    78: 0000000000086000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 heap_spinlock
    79: 00000000000829e0    48 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 stack_alloc
    80: 0000000000086038     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 pmm_tree
    81: 0000000000081b08    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch64_fiq
    82: 0000000000082630   400 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_add
    83: 0000000000082b14   112 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 string_format2s
    84: 0000000000082a40   148 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 compare_string
    85: 00000000000827d8   436 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_debug_walk
    86: 0000000000081af0    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch64_irq
    87: 00000000000819d0    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_sp0_irq
    88: 0000000000081934   132 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main
    89: 00000000000838d8   172 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_next
    90: 00000000000819b8    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_sp0_sync
    91: 00000000000813a0    20 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 heap_add
    92: 0000000000081b80    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch32_ser
    93: 000000000008167c   276 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 heap_free
    94: 0000000000081a18   120 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_spx_sync
    95: 0000000000081b38    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch32_syn
    96: 000000000008382c   172 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_prev
    97: 0000000000081b98   176 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 pmm_compare
    98: 0000000000080c00     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 entry_vbar_el3
    99: 00000000000829d4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 spinlock_release
   100: 0000000000083a20   140 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_walk
   101: 000000000008016c   112 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 dtb_string
   102: 0000000000080500   356 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 elf_kernel_init
   103: 00000000000841e4     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 entry_rodata
   104: 0000000000086020     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 stack_tree
   105: 0000000000086018     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 stack_spinlock
   106: 0000000000086000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 entry_bss
   107: 000000000008377c    88 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_min
   108: 0000000000081aa8    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_spx_fiq
   109: 0000000000081a90    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_curr_el_spx_irq
   110: 0000000000081b20    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch64_ser
   111: 0000000000082a10    48 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 stack_free
   112: 0000000000083984   156 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_find
   113: 0000000000081b68    24 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 main_lower_el_aarch32_fiq
   114: 00000000000835c4   440 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 tree_remove

No version information found in this file.
```

Here is the function posing the problem:

```
int32_t elf_kernel_init(uint64_t addr){
  int32_t rc = 0, i;
  struct elf_hdr* hdr = (struct elf_hdr*) addr;
  struct elf_phdr* phdr;
  struct elf_shdr* shdr;

  if(hdr->mag0 != ELF_HDR_MAG0) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->mag1 != ELF_HDR_MAG1) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->mag2 != ELF_HDR_MAG2) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->mag3 != ELF_HDR_MAG3) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->bits != ELF_HDR_BITS_64) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->data != ELF_HDR_DATA_2LSB) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->fversion != ELF_HDR_FVERSION_CURRENT) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->osabi != ELF_HDR_OSABI_SYSV) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->aversion != 0) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->type != ELF_HDR_TYPE_EXEC) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->machine != ELF_HDR_MACHINE_RISCV) rc = -EINVALID;
  if(hdr->eversion != ELF_HDR_EVERSION_CURRENT) rc = -EINVALID;

  if(rc < 0){
    log("elf: header check failed!\r\n");
    return rc;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is my linker script:

```
ENTRY(entry)

PHDRS{
        text PT_LOAD FILEHDR PHDRS;
        rodata PT_LOAD;
        data PT_LOAD;
        bss PT_LOAD;
}

SECTIONS{
        . = 0x80000;
        .text ALIGN(4K) + SIZEOF_HEADERS : { *(.text) } :text
        .rodata ALIGN(4K) : { *(.rodata) } :rodata
        .data ALIGN(4K) : { *(.data) } :data
        .bss ALIGN(4K) : { *(.bss) } :bss
        /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.note.gnu.property) *(.eh_frame) }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question and tags to include the language you have written the program in, compiler flags and version if applicable and source code

Comment: Here is the error message `main_curr_el_spx_sync: spsr_el3=600003cd, esr_el3=2000000, elr_el3=80500, far_el3=0` and compiled with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mabi=lp64 -march=armv8.1-a -fno-pie -ffreestanding -nostdinc -Wextra -Werror -c xxx`

Comment: You still haven't provided the actual C source code for your program which people will need in order to help you find what's causing the errors.

Comment: I don't think it is the C code , but rather the way the function is called... But I don't know why. I added the option `-fno-pie` to get rid of the `.plt` and `.got` sections inside of the `.data` part because I thought this was the reason...